# Why is chrome rendering web pages so bad?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

Since updating to the latest version, chrome is rendering pages completely wrong. Browsing the web I haven't found people with the same problem. I'm attaching a screenshot for people to better understand what I mean (I attached a GDocs one since it is one of the worst cases). The chrome I'm using is 29.0.1547.57 installed on OSX 10.8.4.

[image: Chrome rendering Google Docs Document Editor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling all extensions, then quit and restart. If the problem does not occur, reenable extensions one at a time until you discover which one causes the issue. At that point you can report the report the issue to the developer of the extension.

Comment: I would like to know what extension does this sprite explosion. It's kind of cool and might be fun to install on someone for … um … research potential…